# YouTube glitch that sporadically inserts a static "subliminal" image for 1 frame of uploaded video

Tags: youtube, video, youtube-channel, youtube-studio

In the following video that I've uploaded to my YouTube channel, a still image from the beginning of the video flashes for 1 frame many times throughout the video. Here's an example right after the 5:48 mark:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIrEM2FbOLU&t=348

The original video stored on my computer (that I uploaded to YouTube) does not have these "glitches".

I reported this to YouTube and they are working to fix the video, so by the time you read this, the problem may no longer exist for this particular video. However, I've seen a few people complain about a similar issue, and so I'm asking a question about whether there is something that can be done to minimize the probability of these glitches?

I'm using 30fps, 1080p, H.264, generated by Premiere. Original video is 59.94fps, but again the exported video at 30fps looks flawless on my machine.

Comment: It's a frame that is pulled from the start of your video and inserted randomly throughout the video. I have this same problem too, but my content is 60fps, not 30fps, generated in OBS with NVENC H.264 encoder at 1080p. Did you fix or figure out how to get it to stop?

Comment: Not yet, contacted YouTube for fix.

Comment: you should check Premiere's encoding settings coz on 99,99% the culprit is there and youtube's codecs are just not sophisticated/complex enough to render/read it correctly, therefore that glitch you experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube regularly messaged me (once every 2 weeks) letting me know that they are working on a fix. Now, 2 months later, they said that the bug is fixed. My video appears to be good now and hope the same is true for other videos that experienced this bug.